# IE default version is changed to 7 automatically

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, compatibility, ie-developer-tools

i have added the bellow piece of code in my js file.

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
meta.content = "IE=edge, IE=11, IE=10, IE=9";
document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

But after changing this My IE browser is changed its default version to 7 from 11.

kindly let me know why it was changed.

Comment: Aside from `US` instead of `UA` in your example code, the meta should probably be provided in the form of static HTML (or via a HTTP response header), not added dynamically via client JS. As for value, use just [`IE=edge`](https://tanalin.com/en/blog/2009/07/disable-ie8-compatibility-mode/) to enable the most modern rendering mode in IE (that `edge` had nothing to do with the new Edge browser).

Answer (score 0):

You have a lost **b** letter in **X-UA-Compatible**.
And you cannot set multiple versions in content.

Comment: missing the b letter is the typo mistake while creating the question

Comment: actually my site needs to support ie 9, 10, 11, and edge browsers. how should I need to add the content? 
However, I have tried as below also
meta.content = "IE=edge";
still am facing the same issue

Comment: If your minimum version is IE 9, than you should set IE=9 to meta.

Answer (score 0):

We could use JavaScript to add meta tag or modify the meta tag content, but, it will be generated after the page is loaded. So, if you use F12 developer tools to check, you can see that: the meta tag content value and the Browser Document mode are not matched.

More details information, please refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

So, in my opinion, I suggest you could directly add meta tag in the head. instead of via JavaScript.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```